# javascript variable name replacing actual value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a javascript function ...

```
function check_val(name, cat)
{
    alert(cat);

    var val = name.indexOf('[');
    if (val == -1){
        //$('input[type="checkbox"][value='+ name + ']')[0].click()      
        val = '"' + name + '"'
        type = "'" + cat + "'"
        $.get(url,{'ajaxtype':'content', type : val}, function(data{$('#search_container').html(data);$('#rotator').hide();});
    }
}
```

when i call this function with argument say `check_val('xyz','pqr')`

The problem is when I check the request.get parameter I am getting

```
<QueryDict: {u'type': [u'"xyz"'], u'ajaxtype': [u'content']}>
```

instead of

```
<QueryDict: {u'pqr': [u'"xyz"'], u'ajaxtype': [u'content']}>
```

Comment: Where did `QueryDict` come from?

Comment: Its a django app... thats why the request.Get is a QueryDictionary (QueryDict) object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the object beforehand and use array subscript syntax:

```
var requestData = { 'ajaxtype': 'content' };
requestData[type] = val;
$.get(url, requestData,
  function(data{$('#search_container').html(data);$('#rotator').hide();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{'ajaxtype':'content', type : val}` try `{'ajaxtype':'content', "'" + cat + "'" : val}`.

This way JS should know that it's not key name but variable.

Comment: No need of single quotes around `cat` I believe

Comment: @thefourtheye Maybe not, but OP wants it.

Comment: calling cat is also giving the same result